# Laravel 5.4 image url stored in variable not seen on blade file

Tags: laravel

I am working on Laravel 5.4 and i use below given code.

```
 @if( $profileurl ) 
    <div class="">
        @php  
        $cropped_img =  "http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/fetch/w_150,h_150,c_thumb,g_face,r_max,f_auto/" . $profileurl ;
        @endphp     
        <img src="{{ $cropped_img }}" height="150" width="150">
     </div> 
  @endif
```

But problem is that image is not seen properly. But its url is correct.
[The image is look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAExc.png)

Generated url is http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/fetch/w_150,h_150,c_thumb,g_face,r_max,f_auto/http://dev1.jdsoftvera.com/voting-system/public/profile/image/9ccca1ccad318a91a0a1c057663548b6Penguins.jpg

But the url is ok.

When i simply use this below code then image is seen.

 `<img src="{{ $profileurl }}" height="150" width="150">`

Comment: What is the full generated url? Also, I don`t think you need the $cropped_img variable. Just put your code within the {{ }} tags.

Comment: is it `w_150,h_150,c_thumb,g_face,r_max,f_auto` your folder name?

Comment: Echo the value of '$cropped_img' and make sure what it returns is a valid url and exists on your server.

Comment: Have you tried `{!! $cropped_img !!}` ?

Comment: how does the `src` attr look like when you inspect the `html` code in your browser?

Comment: @linktoahref that could work in the short run but since you are echoing unescaped html one could theoretically perform xss by the file name (if the names are user generated)

Comment: This also not working @linktohref

Comment: @Amar Aly img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/fetch/w_150,h_150,c_thumb,g_face,r_max,f_auto/http://dev1.jdsoftvera.com/voting-system/public/profile/image/9ccca1ccad318a91a0a1c057663548b6Penguins.jpg"

Comment: do you have any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @Amr Aly no error

Answer (score 0):

This code is worked for me.

`$profileurl =  "http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/fetch/w_150,h_150,c_thumb,g_face,r_max,f_auto/" . $profileurl ;
 $img = base64_encode($profileurl);
 $profileurl = base64_decode($img);`